# CSV Importing in SQLite3 results in INSERT failed: Datatype mismatch

Tags: excel, sqlite, csv

When importing a simple csv file made with excel into SQLite, I get an error for each row stating that INSERT failed: Datatype mismatch.

The table schema is a simple id INTEGER PRIMARYKEY AUTOINCREMENT and name TEXT.

The csv is formatted as follows:

```
id,name
1,John Doe
...,...
```

I am importing it with

```
.mode csv
.separator ","
.import table.csv table
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSV file created with excel was exported in Unicode mode because of special characters. Excel produced a file encoded in UTF-16, but SQLite doesn't handle that gracefully. Reencoding the file to UTF-8 fixed this error.